# How to distinguish p and v sounds?

Tags: pronunciación, lingüística

I find the p and v sounds are almost the same. For instance, 'por favor' sounds like 'por fapor' to me. Any tip or pedagogical method to resolve this issue?

Comment: Esos sonidos no son iguales NI AHÍ. El mapeo al IPA es p = /p/, y v = /β/, son parecidos a la ‘p’ y ‘b’ del inglés pero en castellano se hacen más exagerados y tal vez eso te confunda. Ahora bien, hay mucho por determinar; si alguien realmente te dice ‘por fapor’ con una pe bien evidente, eso es subestándar así que respondele ‘Eh, flaco, así no se pronuncia eh’.

Comment: HAcé una cosa: mirá el movimiento de los labios a la vez que escuchás. Eso me ayuda mucho para captar los diferentes fonemas del inglés que nosotros no tenemos y distinguir entre palabras parecidas.

Comment: First, resolve it in English: pees and vees. Also, what is **your native language**? You are failing to make the right point of articulation with the v. The teeth have to touch the lower lip. Whereas with p, you close and open the lips while letting air out.

Comment: But, v in Spanish words are not pronounced as [v] as they do in English words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your mother language lacks the difference between voiced and voiceless sounds, or it is not too prominent. I've met Arabic-speaking people who had trouble with the sounds `/b/`, `/v/`, `/p/`, `/f/` (they all sound the same to them), and the same happens with speakers of many Asian languages, like Chinese, which have a much stronger emphasis on palatal/non palatal sounds, which are nearly indistinguishable for us (I find it very hard to tell `sh` from `x`, for instance, in Chinese).

The only *trick* I can think of is trying to pronounce the words yourself and noticing the difference. `/b/` and `/p/` are the same sound, excepting for `/b/` being voiced and `/p/`, voiceless. Put you lips almost together and try to make a buzzing sound for a couple of seconds; then close your lips and pronounce an `/e/` immediately after: that will make the `/b/` sound. If you do the same, but without the buzzing, that will make the `/p/` sound. With some practice, you will have no difficulty telling those sounds apart.

Comment: ok ,pero escuchar la /b/ obstructiva en “por favor” no es muy natural que digamos... un nativo auténtico diría /poɾ fa'β̞oɾ/. Es decir, en la pe se bloquea todo el aire y en la be se lo deja correr

Comment: So the IPA notation for these similar sounds (phonics?) are [p] [b] [β] and what else?

Comment: @qazwsx In Spanish, `b` and `v` sound `[b]`, `p` sounds `[p]` and `f` sounds `[f]`. We have no `[β]` sound.

Comment: @Gorpik En qué frasco vivís? (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aproximante_bilabial) ‘En el español la consonante bilabial aproximante es uno de los alófonos del fonema /b/, **correspondiente a la pronunciación habitual de las letras b y v en posición media** como por ejemplo en vivo [biβ̞o]’. Por lo tanto, no queda bien decir /fa'boɾ/. Pronuncialo, con la ‘p’ el aire se corta por completo mientras que con la ‘b’ se lo deja correr. Por eso, mi temor es que le estén pronunciando mal y por eso no los pueda distinguir.